# Git: How to merge individual file that cannot be inspected?

Tags: git, merge

I am trying to pull a Unity project from github, and there is a conflict in the asset database.

I fixed this earlier by deleting and cloning...but I would like to be able to merge this.

The current state is a partial merge: I have inspected the conflicts (all are in binary files), and kept the remote version each time (I haven't changed anything since last syncing.

However, the asset database (a database, obviously) is un-viewable in the merge tool (p4mergetool), so I can't go through the merge process.

How do I choose to keep the remote database?  I tried running the answers I found online:

```
git checkout --theirs "path"
```

and nothing happened...

Comment: `git checkout --theirs "path"; git add "path"`

Comment: @PetSerAl: the `git add` should be unnecessary, since `git checkout` writes the checked-out file to the index as well as to the work-tree.

Comment: @torek `git checkout --theirs` checkout stage 3 from index into working directory. So you are claiming it also collapse unmerged index entities as well?

Comment: I *think* it does.  It's not clear from documentation, probably need to test it to verify.  Note that `git checkout MERGE_HEAD -- path` definitely does update the index version (but is subtly different since it gets the named `path` from `MERGE_HEAD`, not from the index, so it behaves differently on detected renames).

Comment: @PetSerAl  I'll delete in an hour if you don't want the answer accepted

Comment: @PetSerAl: ok, testing proves that you *do* have to `git add` the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two straightforward options for doing this within Git (without using any of the p4 tools).  One, probably the better one in general, is (as [PetSerAl answered in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929779/git-how-to-merge-individual-file-that-cannot-be-inspected#comment63311177_37929779)):

```
git checkout --theirs "path"; git add "path"
```

The first part, `git checkout --theirs`, extracts the other branch version (the one you are calling "remote" here; that's one of several names various tools use to try to tell which file is which) into the work-tree.  The second part, `git add`, marks the file as "resolved".

Another (not quite as good in some ways) method is:

```
git checkout MERGE_HEAD "path"
```

This looks—and is!—simpler: it tells Git to extract the `MERGE_HEAD` version (the `--theirs` or "remote" version) of the given path, and as a side effect, marks the file resolved.

In *most* cases (including yours, here) these two do exactly the same thing.

#### When are they different?

The one case where they do something different occurs when Git decides that a file was renamed.  Consider the following example:

```
$ mkdir mergetest; cd mergetest; git init
Initialized empty Git repository in [...]/mergetest/.git/
$ echo repo for merge example > README
$ git add README; git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 74ad4af] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
```

We now have a repository with no files yet (except for a README).  Let's make a file with some fairly significant content that Git can detect easily enough even if we modify and rename it:

```
$ cp /etc/termcap termcap; chmod 644 termcap
$ git add termcap; git commit -m 'add termcap'
[master de3d189] add termcap
 1 file changed, 4666 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 termcap
```

Now let's set up to have two branches, and make changes to the termcap copy in each branch, so that we can get a merge conflict.

```
$ git branch A; git checkout -b B
Switched to a new branch 'B'
```

In our B branch, let's change the last few lines a bit:

```
$ tail -3 termcap
#
# END OF TERMCAP
# ------------------------
$ ed termcap
208311
$-1s/TERMCAP/LINE/p
# END OF LINE
w
208308
q
$ git add termcap; git commit -m 'Tron MCP says END OF LINE!'
[B 9f40f2d] Tron MCP says END OF LINE!
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Now we'll change the file in an incompatible way in branch A:

```
$ git checkout A
Switched to branch 'A'
$ ed termcap
208311
$-1s/TERMCAP/FILE/p
# END OF FILE
w
208308
q
$ git add termcap; git commit -m 'incompatible change'
[A 9aae164] incompatible change
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

We're almost ready to merge, but that will be somewhat boring, so let's make one more change now: we'll rename `termcap`.

```
$ git mv termcap stocking-cap
$ git commit -m rename
[A 713eddd] rename
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename termcap => stocking-cap (100%)
```

Now we can try to merge from B:

```
$ git merge B
Auto-merging stocking-cap
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in stocking-cap
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git status
On branch A
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:   stocking-cap

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Note that Git now refers to the file, not as `termcap`, but as `stocking-cap`.  The conflict is between our Tron-ish END OF LINE phrase, which we applied to a file named `termcap`, and our `END OF FILE` phrase, which we applied to `termcap` as well but then we renamed to `stocking-cap`.

If we attempt to check out `termcap` from `MERGE_HEAD`, we get an error instead:

```
$ git checkout MERGE_HEAD stocking-cap
error: pathspec 'stocking-cap' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

The file is known, in the tip of branch `B` (aka `MERGE_HEAD`), as `termcap`, not as `stocking-cap`.  But if we `git checkout --theirs` it works:

```
$ git checkout --theirs stocking-cap
$ tail -3 stocking-cap
#
# END OF LINE
# ------------------------
```

There we go: the file is still renamed, but we got "their" version, which in MERGE_HEAD is known as `termcap`.  The file is still in unmerged state though, as `git status` will show (try it), or as seen in `git ls-files --stage`:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 666e31eff490e17863f3261a0c16df0cdf8ca69f 0   README
100644 30e251d0e75b4905449a052b5f04e316b15ffd46 1   stocking-cap
100644 941c1fa9c08e7dc0c5b8fd8e033708e6a66e4166 2   stocking-cap
100644 f6282a43f57b2acf2561ccbc58b817e21ae13b07 3   stocking-cap
```

We must `git add stocking-cap` to resolve it:

```
$ git add stocking-cap
$ git status -s
M  stocking-cap
```

and now we can commit:

```
$ git commit -m 'completed the merge'
[A c0a3dad] completed the merge
```

and view diffs:

```
 $ git diff A B
diff --git a/stocking-cap b/termcap
similarity index 100%
rename from stocking-cap
rename to termcap
```

and logs:

```
$ git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all
*   c0a3dad (HEAD -> A) completed the merge
|\  
| * 9f40f2d (B) Tron MCP says END OF LINE!
* | 713eddd rename
* | 9aae164 incompatible change
|/  
* de3d189 (master) add termcap
* 74ad4af initial
```

and so on.

#### Recap

You may use `git checkout MERGE_HEAD`, which extracts the file from the other commit (`B` in our example here) and lets you skip the `git add` step, but requires the file name to be unchanged.  Or, you may use `git checkout --theirs`, which extracts the file from the other commit, *and* handles renames, *but* forces you to `git add` the result.